# How to load eloquent morph relation with per-model conditions?

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

Let say we have following tables:

```
Question: id, questionable_type, questionable_id, body

Post: id, type, body

Country: id, type, continent
```

Post and Country both are questionable. How can we eager load questions with their morph relation with *separate conditions per model*?

For example: How to retrieve questions with questionable relation where `type = 'single'` (*if questionable model is Post*) *or* where `continent = 'asia'` (*if questionable model is Country*)?

Answer (score 1):

I think [whereHasMorph](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-polymorphic-relationships) is the query function that you need:

```
$questions = App\Question::with('questionable')
    ->whereHasMorph(
    'questionable',
    ['App\Post', 'App\Country'],
    function (Builder $query, $type) {
        if ($type === 'App\Post') {
            $query->orWhere('type', 'single');
        }

        if ($type === 'App\Country') {
            $query->orWhere('continent', 'asia');
        }
    }
)->get();
```